# Seems margin is have a problem with fixed position in css

Tags: html, css

I have a div with `width: 100%` that is fixed to the bottom with `position: fixed; and bottom: 0;`

I can add margin to the fixed div and it will affect left, top, bottom, but it doesn't affect right. Why is this? And what's the possible way out without modifying `width: 100%`

Some code

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
}
body{
  background: blue;
}
#show_well{
  background: orange;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="show_well">a</div>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="g.css"> -->
</body>

</html>
```

**Example of what I see:**

[image: Left]

**Next**

[image: Right]

First is left, and next is right. I need the div that's orange in the images to have margin that is equal left, top, bottom, and right. The margin seems to not work at the right if in fixed position.

Comment: Some real code? — These tags don't live all alone and the unmentioned environment has some influence that you want to be explaned.

Comment: I'm very unclear what effect you are aiming for if the div has width 100% (100% of what?) and a right hand margin. Could you create a runnable snippet which you are sure demonstrates the problem see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @dodrg and @A Haworth I'll update it now.

Comment: What effect are you expecting with a right margin on an element that has full viewport width?

Comment: @A Haworth   The margin for right isn't working with that code in the question.

Comment: You have set the width to 100% so any margin isn’t going to show on the right. A simple if slightly hacks way to fix it may be to set the width to 98%

Comment: @AHaworth It works but I'm quite unsure why it floops with 99%.

Comment: Because you asked for a left margin of 1% and a right margin of 1% and if you want to fit all that in it means you've only got 98% left for your actual element.

Comment: @AHaworth alright, thought likewise earlier.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but why don't you use left and right to change the positioning?

Comment: Please could you show a picture of what you want it to look like as you can’t have a width of 100% plus left and right margins of 1% each fitting into the viewport. You could use box-sizing and borders to put a white frame round  if that is the visual look you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no actual problem with the right hand margin - but you can't see it because the sum total of the width plus margins is wider than the viewport.

If you can't alter the width of the element from 100% what you can do to achieve the look of margins on all sides is to instead give it a border the same color as the parent background.

Then use box-sizing to make the border part of the overall width of the element. Note this gives the visual effect but of course the amount of the element that is visible is reduced to accommodate the border.

This gives this look:

[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: blue;
}

#show_well {
  background: orange;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 1vw blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="show_well">a</div>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="g.css"> -->
</body>

</html>
```